# Atomic potential energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics

Imagine in the entire universe, there is only 1 electron and 1 proton, initially spaced $x$ distance apart. As we let the system evolve over time, it seems obvious they will accelerate towards one another and, presumably, merge to form an atom.  But the atom will have energy equal to the ground state of hydrogen plus the original electric potential energy, which I believe would be a maximum of 13.6 eV.

My question is, how does this atom form and relax to the ground state? Does it "start out" with the electron in a very high energy shell, and then spontaneously emit a UV photon?  Do the charges continually emit photons as they accelerate, shedding the kinetic energy as they go?  Is there a possibility the two could bounce back apart if the excess energy were not shed right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have described photo-recombination. Going from an unbound to a bound state results in the emission of one or more photons at a continuum of energies. Classically, the light is emitted because the electron (and to a much lesser extent, the proton) are accelerated by the electric field of the other.

Photo-recombination is more likely to result in the electron ending up in an excited bound state. The usual, spontaneous emission, which may be very slow, will then allow the hydrogen atom to assume the ground state.

Answer (score 1):

Any accelerating charge must give off electromagnetic radiation, so both the electron and the proton will lose energy as they approach each other. Once they reach close enough and make the hydrogen atom, I'm not sure the electron will have shed enough energy to already be in the ground state. That seems unlikely, as the amount of energy lost depends on the travel distance, $x$.

The electron will most probably be in an excited state due to all the excess kinetic energy it has, but it will eventually get down to the ground state by emitting a photon with energy equal to the difference in the energies of the two states.